# Xcode - Archives not in organizer

Tags: xcode

Today I was looking to make an archive in Xcode 12 and suddenly I can no longer see the Archives in Window -> Organizer (it will not open automatically as supposed). It will show me the alert with Build Succeeded but no archive to upload on Test Flight. I was looking in `~Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives` and is there but I can't see it in Organizer.

Any reason and maybe a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct app selected. For example, this app I have no archives shown:

[image: Empty window]

But once I select the correct app, it works:

[image: Click on the top left button and select the correct app]

[image: Archives are not empty]

Comment: Not working for me as I have the app selected

Comment: Are you sure you made the archive? Anything in the Filter box?

Comment: `Archiving MyProject: MyProject` after I do Product -> Archive and then `MyProject | Archive MyProject: Succeeded`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution for this. So I was using `react native mapbox` package which seem to have some pods issues as per this thread https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1097#issuecomment-770064084

Looks like the archive was malformed

Answer (score 0):

**Try the follow:**

1 - Close XCode.

2 - Go to /Library/Developer/XCode/Archives.

3 - Find the .xarchive file that you just archived.

4 - Delete the folders that are not the targets that you just archived (if exist):

```
Products/Applications/your-app-dev.app

Products/Applications/your-app-stage.app
```

5 - Open the Info.plist file (still from the .xarchive file).

6 - Complete the file with the part that is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ApplicationPath</key>
        <string>Applications/your-app.app</string>
        <key>Architectures</key>
        <array>
            <string>arm64</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.your-app.app</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>2.2</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>42</string>
        <key>SigningIdentity</key>
        <string>Apple Development: Your Name (SOMEKEY123)</string>
        <key>Team</key>
        <string>123456789</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ArchiveVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2021-05-16T00:28:17Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>your-app</string>
    <key>SchemeName</key>
    <string>your-app</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```